# Enviar login e senha no email JavaMail

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet, javamail

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web utilizando jsp e servlet e gostaria de que quando enviar o e-mail passa-se uma imagem e o login e senha mas o e-mail só enviar a imagem e não envia o login e senha.

Imagem com o erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Servlet

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);


    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

    String email = request.getParameter("email");

        String assunto = "Cadastro de dados do EccomeceJSP2";
        EnviarEmailGmail gm = new EnviarEmailGmail();
        gm.enviarGmail(email, assunto, login, senha);
```

Classe responsável pelo envio

```
public class EnviarEmailGmail {

    static Session session;

public void enviarGmail(String email, String assunto, String login, String senha){
try {

  final String username = "meuemail@gmail.com";
    final String password = "minhasenha";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  

     session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("meuemail@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(email));
        message.setSubject(assunto);
        //message.setText("Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso e seu login e senha será <br> " + "Login:" + login + "Senha:" + senha);


   MimeMultipart multipart2 = new MimeMultipart("related");

    // first part  (the html)
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String htmlText = "<H3>Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso e seu login e senha será:</H3><br><b>Login:+login+</b><br><b>Senha:+senha+</b><br><br><img src=\"cid:image\">";
    messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

    // add it
    multipart2.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // second part (the image)
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource
      ("C:\\imagens\\eccomerce.JPG");
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");

    // add it
    multipart2.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // put everything together
    message.setContent(multipart2);


        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
     }

    }
```

Comment: Você já nao fez essa pergunta e apagou? Se estiver recriando a mesma pergunta, aconselho a parar pois isso pode gerar suspensao do site.

Comment: Não é a mesma pergunta o problema que tinha colocado na outra pergunta consegui resolver, essa é outra pergunta com problema diferente

Comment: Então o titulo é parecido. Como dica, procure escrever um titulo que seja mais condizente com o problema e não um que seja generico e repetitivo, isso ajuda até a sua pergunta a ser localizada com mais facilidade, aumentando suas chances de obter respostas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o problema está na linha:

```
String htmlText = "<H3>Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso e seu login e senha será:</H3><br><b>Login:+login+</b><br><b>Senha:+senha+</b><br><br><img src=\"cid:image\">";
```

troque por

```
String htmlText = "<H3>Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso e seu login e senha será:</H3><br><b>Login: " + login + "</b><br><b>Senha: " + senha + "</b><br><br><img src=\"cid:image\">";
```